# If statements in C

Tags: c, if-statement

I have a problem with my code, I want the code to check if the `name` is equal to the `realname` and print what's inside of the `if` statement, otherwise, to print what's inside of the `else` statement, at the end of the code it says what it throws.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    char name[5];
    char realname[] = "Mike";

    printf("Please, enter your name: ");
    fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
    scanf(name, realname);

    if (strcmp(name, realname))
    {
        printf("Nice to meet you %s ", name );
        printf("I'm known as robot. ");
        printf("And welcome to starting.com");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You're not the owner of this account.");
    }

}
//If i type "john" it returns this.
//Please, enter your name: john
//Nice to meet you john I'm known as machinecode. And welcome to starting.com
```

Comment: `if (strcmp(name, realname))` --> `if (strcmp(name, realname) == 0)`

Comment: `scanf(name, realname);` hmm... what do you expect this to do?

Comment: I think you meant `sscanf` instead of `scanf`. Actually, I'm not sure why you would even want to do any scanf after the previous `fgets`. Seems kinda redundant.

Comment: @smac89: Well, ``fscanf`` followed by `sscanf` can be used for some lightweight data validation and parsing.  At a minimum, it could be useful in this program to strip leading and trailing whitespace. But the OP isn’t close to using it correctly.

Comment: `char name[5]` is OK if someone is called "Mike", "Bob" or "Eve". But not if they are called "Miranda Veracruz de la Jolla Cardinal".

Answer (score 3):

`strcmp` returns `0` when both arguments passed to it are equal, and `0` is a "false" value in C. In short, you have your condition reversed. The most readable way to write it, IMHO, is to explicitly compare the result of `strcmp` to `0`:

```c
if (strcmp(name, realname) == 0)
{
    printf("Nice to meet you %s ", name );
    printf("I'm known as robot. ");
    printf("And welcome to starting.com");
}
else
{
    printf("You're not the owner of this account.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have (at least) 3 bugs/misunderstandings in your code.

1. `strcmp` return value

   It seems you expect `strcmp` to return something like "TRUE" if the strings are equal. But that's not how `strcmp` works. If two strings are equal it returns zero. Zero in an `if` controlling expression is like "FALSE", i.e. the substatement won't be executed. You need to compare the return value to zero, like `if (strcmp(name, realname) == 0)`
2. `scanf` usages

   This part `scanf(name, realname);` is strange. I'm not sure what you expect it to do but as it is, the makes no sense. Delete the line.
3. `fgets` usages

   `fgets` reads the std input **including** the newline character. So before comparing strings, you need to remove that newline character. However, if the provided buffer is too small to hold the typed input, `fgets` will only store BUFFER-SIZE-1 characters and there will be no newline. You need to handle that case as well. See this question: [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/4386427)

So, your code could be:

```
int main()
{
    char name[5];
    char realname[] = "Mike";

    printf("Please, enter your name: ");
    fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);
    name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = 0;

    if (strcmp(name, realname) == 0)
    {
        printf("Nice to meet you %s ", name );
        printf("I'm known as robot. ");
        printf("And welcome to starting.com");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("You're not the owner of this account.");
    }

}
```

Comment: 4th bug - name is too short. Needs room for newline and null.

Comment: @stark nice catch but... If the input is "Mike<newline>", `fgets` will actually store "Mike\0" and skip the newline. So it's actually possible to get a match even with `char name[5];`

Comment: It will not skip the newline. It will still be in the input stream.

Comment: @stark true.. By "skip" I wanted to say that the newline would not be copied into the buffer. Therefore it will be possible to get an input that match `realname`. Anyway - I agree that `name` is too short for any practical use.